# Node.js I keep getting Promise { <pending> } when I make an API call then try to save results to variable and then log to console

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, axios

I create a function asyncFunc which makes an asynchronous request. How can I return the response/result from asyncFunc and then save the result into a variable to use later or to print to console? below is what I have so far. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
var axios = require('axios');

async function asyncFunc() {
    // fetch data from a url endpoint
    const data = await axios.get("/some_url_endpoint");
    return data;
}

var text = asyncFunc()
console.log(text)
```

this is my result when I log to console: Promise {  }

Comment: `asyncFunction().then(response => console.log(response.data));`

Comment: In case you're interested, [here](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html) is a good reference to read more about Promises for asynchronous programming. (You might want to read [this](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_async.html) first).

Comment: I will really like to save the results into a variable so that I can use it later for something else... examples pass the results into another function, write to a database, perform a filter or post the results into another API.